# Random two text fields and buttons using get_sub_field();?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

In the code bellow I created a random text for banner_text and banner_text_two.
Know I wanna be able to append/display BUTTON 1 when displaying banner_text, and BUTTON 2 when displaying banner_text_two.

```
Here is my random code for the two text fields:

<div class="plat">
    <?php $random_text = array(
        get_sub_field( 'banner_text' ),
        get_sub_field( 'banner_text_two' ),
    );
    $rand = rand( 0, 1 );
    echo $random_text[ $rand ]; ?>
</div>

BUTTON 1:

<a class="landing-page button" href="<?php echo home_url( '/superfly/' ); ?>">
<?php _e( 'Skateboard', 'superfly' ); ?> <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></a>

BUTTON 2:

<a class="landing-page button" href="<?php echo home_url( '/fly/' ); ?>">
<?php _e( 'Fly away', 'fly' ); ?> <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php if($rand == 0){?>
   <a class="landing-page button" href="<?php echo home_url( '/superfly/' ); ?>">
<?php _e( 'Skateboard', 'superfly' ); ?> <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></a>
<?php }else{ ?>
   <a class="landing-page button" href="<?php echo home_url( '/superfly/' ); ?>">
<?php _e( 'Skateboard', 'superfly' ); ?> <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></a>
<?php } ?>
```